# Creating bundles in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the best way to create an empty bundle in Cocoa? I bundle in OS X is really nothing but a folder, the only difference being that you have to right-click and do "Show Package Contents" to see the contents, right?

Well, I want a bundle in that sense. After that I will put some files of my choice into it, such as a bunch of plist files. The reason I want to do this is so that my file structure (in, say, the AppSupport folder) will look nicer at the root level.

Related question: How do I tell OS X that a folder ending with ".myappFoo" should be treated as a bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The starting place for information is the Apple developer's doc [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100-SW1).

> The Finder considers a directory to be
>   a package if any of the following
>   conditions are true:
>
> The directory has a known filename
>   extension: .app, .bundle, .framework,
>   .plugin, .kext, and so on.
>
> The directory has an extension that
>   some other application claims
>   represents a package type; see
>   “Document Packages.”
>
> The directory has its package bit set.

The .myAppfoo showing as a bundle is done as a [Document Package](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW1)